# How to find the row with the highest value cell based on another column from within a group of values?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table:

| Site_ID | Volume | RPT_Date | RPT_Hour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 01/01/2021 | 1 |
| 1 | 7 | 01/01/2021 | 2 |
| 1 | 13 | 01/01/2021 | 3 |
| 1 | 11 | 01/16/2021 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 01/16/2021 | 2 |
| 1 | 5 | 01/16/2021 | 3 |
| 2 | 9 | 01/01/2021 | 1 |
| 2 | 24 | 01/01/2021 | 2 |
| 2 | 16 | 01/01/2021 | 3 |
| 2 | 18 | 01/16/2021 | 1 |
| 2 | 7 | 01/16/2021 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 01/16/2021 | 3 |

I need to select the RPT_Hour with the highest Volume for each set of dates

Needed Output:

| Site_ID | Volume | RPT_Date | RPT_Hour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 13 | 01/01/2021 | 1 |
| 1 | 11 | 01/16/2021 | 1 |
| 2 | 24 | 01/01/2021 | 2 |
| 2 | 18 | 01/16/2021 | 1 |

```sql
SELECT site_id, volume, rpt_date, rpt_hour
  FROM (SELECT t.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() 
                OVER (PARTITION BY site_id, rpt_date ORDER BY volume DESC) AS rn        
          FROM MyTable) t
 WHERE rn = 1;
```

I cannot figure out how to group the table into like date groups. If I could do that, I think the rn = 1 will return the highest volume row for each date.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, your query is OK (but `rpt_hour` in desired output is not).

```
SQL> with test (site_id, volume, rpt_date, rpt_hour) as
  2    (select 1, 10, date '2021-01-01', 1 from dual union all
  3     select 1,  7, date '2021-01-01', 2 from dual union all
  4     select 1, 13, date '2021-01-01', 3 from dual union all
  5     select 1, 11, date '2021-01-16', 1 from dual union all
  6     select 1,  3, date '2021-01-16', 2 from dual union all
  7     select 1,  5, date '2021-01-16', 3  from dual union all
  8     --
  9     select 2,  9, date '2021-01-01', 1 from dual union all
 10     select 2, 24, date '2021-01-01', 3 from dual union all
 11     select 2, 16, date '2021-01-01', 3 from dual union all
 12     select 2, 18, date '2021-01-16', 1 from dual union all
 13     select 2,  7, date '2021-01-16', 2 from dual union all
 14     select 2,  1, date '2021-01-16', 3 from dual
 15    ),
 16  temp as
 17    (select t.*,
 18       row_number() over (partition by site_id, rpt_date order  by volume desc) rn
 19     from test t
 20    )
 21  select site_id, volume, rpt_date, rpt_hour
 22  from temp
 23  where rn = 1
 24  /

   SITE_ID     VOLUME RPT_DATE     RPT_HOUR
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1         13 01/01/2021          3
         1         11 01/16/2021          1
         2         24 01/01/2021          3
         2         18 01/16/2021          1

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using **`MAX(..) KEEP (DENSE_RANK ..) OVER (PARTITION BY ..)`** analytic function without need of any subquery such as :

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
       site_id, 
       MAX(volume) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY volume DESC) OVER 
                               (PARTITION BY site_id, rpt_date) AS volume,
       rpt_date,          
       MAX(rpt_hour) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY volume DESC) OVER
                                 (PARTITION BY site_id, rpt_date) AS rpt_hour
  FROM t
 GROUP BY site_id, rpt_date, volume, rpt_hour 
 ORDER BY site_id, rpt_date
```

**<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=35e2cc17059ac910136138a1aeb678ab)</kbd>**